# Android, Xamarin - How to install different versions of the same app on the same device?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to have two versions of my app installed on my Android at the same time. One for develop and one for test. I've tried to set different app names and package names, but they still overwrite eachother.

What do I need to change for them to appear as different apps on the device?

Comment: Just package name has to be different. Nothing else.

Comment: In your `build.gradle` file, in `defaultConfig` change `applicationId` to new package name

Comment: There is no build.gradle file

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see you mentioned for `Xamarin`. Please see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21473090/5352802